# Driver code for Leet Code problem "Intersection of two linked lists"

Tags: python, linked-list

I am looking at Leet Code problem [160. Intersection of Two Linked Lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/):

> Given the heads of two singly linked-lists `headA` and `headB`, return *the node at which the two lists intersect*. If the two linked lists have no intersection at all, return `null`.
>
> For example, the following two linked lists begin to intersect at node `c1`:
>
> [image]
>
> The test cases are generated such that there are no cycles anywhere in the entire linked structure.
>
> **Note** that the linked lists must **retain their original structure** after the function returns.

I am trying to find the driver code for the following solution, but have been unsuccessful. How can I run this code for some example input?

```
Class Solution:
    def getIntersectionNode(self, headA, headB):
        Alst = {}
        
        while headA is not None:
            Alst[headA] = headA
            headA = headA.next
        
        while headB is not None:
            if headB in Alst:
                return headB
            headB = headB.next
        return None
```

Comment: What do you mean with "driver code"? Code that creates `headA` and `headB`? Can you give an example of what you expect as input for the driver code? Note that information that is essential for understanding the question should not be behind a link, but embedded in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

On Leet Code the input is parsed and linked lists are created before the solution code is executed.

Here are some functions you could use for problems like these:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None


def createLinkedList(values):
    head = None
    if values:
        itertor = iter(values)
        node = head = ListNode(next(itertor))
        for value in itertor:
            node.next = ListNode(value)
            node = node.next
    return head


def intersectLinkedLists(intersectValue, listA, listB, skipA, skipB):
    if intersectValue == 0:
        return
    for _ in range(skipA-1):
        listA = listA.next
    for _ in range(skipB):
        listB = listB.next
    listA.next = listB
    if listA.next.val != intersectValue or listB.val != intersectValue:
        raise ValueError("Intersection value not found")
    return listB
```

Add to that your solution code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def getIntersectionNode(self, headA, headB):
        Alst = {}
        while headA is not None:
            Alst[headA] = headA
            headA = headA.next
        while headB is not None:
            if headB in Alst:
                return headB
            headB = headB.next
        return None
```

And finally, define some input. Here is how that would look for the example input that Leet Code loads by default:

```
# Inputs
intersectionValue = 8
valuesA = [4,1,8,4,5]
valuesB = [5,6,1,8,4,5]
skipA = 2
skipB = 3

# Conversion
listA = createLinkedList(valuesA)
listB = createLinkedList(valuesB)
intersection = intersectLinkedLists(intersectionValue, listA, listB, skipA, skipB)

# Run solution code
s = Solution()
answer = s.getIntersectionNode(listA, listB)

# Verify
print("Correct" if answer == intersection else "Wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

pretty intuitive solution:

```
class Solution:
    def getIntersectionNode(self, headA: ListNode, headB: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        cur_A,cur_B =headA,headB
        len_A =0
        while cur_A:
            cur_A =cur_A.next
            len_A+=1
        len_B =0
        while cur_B:
            cur_B =cur_B.next
            len_B+=1
        # So far found the length of both linked lists
        # Now decide which one is short_list or long_list
        if len_A >len_B:
            long_list =headA
            short_list =headB
            diff =len_A -len_B
        else:
            long_list =headB
            short_list =headA
            diff =len_B -len_A
        i=0
        while i<diff:
            long_list=long_list.next
            i+=1
        # at this point we are at the same level of both l inked lists
        while long_list!=short_list:
            long_list=long_list.next
            short_list=short_list.next
        return long_list
```